# Android Studio 3.5 Canary 7: “Apply Code Changes” is disabled

Tags: android-studio

I am using **Android Studio 3.5 Canary 7**. When I debug my project, "[Apply Code Changes](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/#apply-changes)" is disabled in the menu. At one time this worked on my project, but today doesn't. What settings should I check to allow this to work?

Comment: I had the same issue I was using an emulator with API level 23 as per android documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/#apply-changes you need to use API level 26 or higher

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for quite a long time. I was planning to do **Invalidate Caches and Restart**.  But in that way I would lose all my Local History and didn't wanted that to happen.

So all I did was instead of choosing **Invalidate Caches and Restart**, I chose **Just Restart**. And then Booyah!!!. It fixed the issue.

All the folks out there who are struggling in this issue, do try my solution once and let me know if it works.

Comment: Sorry, it did not worked. Nor Just Reastart nor Invalidate Caches and Restart.

Comment: @AbigailLa'Fay , now version 3.5 has been released in the stable channel. Try to update Android Studio from that channel and tell me if the issue still persists.

Comment: I wrote after 3.5 update and still don't work with my Zebra TC20 device. It has 7.1.2 Android version.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project in Android Studio 3.5 and seeing if "Apply Changes" option is shown in this case?